# Vanity URL redirection

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a setup for vanity URLs that redirects `http://localhost/username/` to `http://localhost/profile.php?id=username`

For example, `http://localhost/testuser/` and `http://localhost/testuser` link to `http://localhost/profile.php?id=testuser` and the address bar reads `http://localhost/testuser/`

However, this stops working if there is a folder of the same name in the directory. Then `http://localhost/testuser/` links correctly, but when I try to access `http://localhost/testuser`, the address bar shows `http://localhost/testuser/?user=testuser` .

My htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Ideally the rule should check if the username exists in the SQL database (I have the code for this already), and if it does, it should redirect to `http://localhost/profile.php?id=username` while keeping the address bar as `http://localhost/username/`. And this should happen even if a folder of that name exists.

Comment: `Ideally the rule should check if the username exists in the SQL database` No, `mod_rewrite` cannot query your database, only your code can do that.

Comment: Sorry for making that unclear, I meant that code should check that! As I said above, I have this part of it working as well. The error is only happening if a subdirectory of that name exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty interesting problem. I came up with this work-around:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# when user name != directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

# when user name == directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If user-name is same as a folder name then only 3rd rule will fire and that too after trailing slash has been added by `mod_dir`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I do this if I want to redirect them to a URL that is a non php file? Would it follow a similar pattern?

For example if I want to redirect localhost/example/ to localhost/profile/example/, would this be correct? (I tried but this does not work)

`RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /profile/$1/ [L,QSA]`

Also what is the difference between rule 2 and 3? Not the condition checking, the actual rewrite rule I see there is an extra "?" in rule 2 which does not exist in rule 3!

Comment: Rule #3 is executed after `mod_dir` has added trailing slash after a directory name. But rule is executed for a non-directory making trailing slash optional.

Comment: So am I right to say that regardless of whether or not the given name is a folder name, it will always redirect to profile_Redirect.php? (Of course, the folder name ones would lead to 404 not found or some such thing, while legit names would show the actual profile)

Comment: Yes that's correct regardless of whether or not the given name is a folder name, it will always rewrite to `profile_Redirect.php`

Comment: Also would `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /profile/$1/ [L,QSA]` redirect to `localhost/profile/name` ?

Comment: Yes it will but you should keep it as: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile/$1/ [L]` Also request you to please keep comment section to discuss current answer and feel free to create new question in case you have more rewrite rules requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning directory slash off. But be forewarned that this opens up an information disclosure issue:

> Security Warning
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.

But if you don't actually access any directories, then you can just:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: I have several other pages and subdirectories and files in the directory! So this may not be a valid option.

Ideally the easiest way to do this would be to use a subdirectory for this (Eg : localhost/profiles/username), but I am trying to keep that as a last resort, and instead push to achieve localhost/username